# Write 10-bit number and 6-bit number to short?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am writing a program where one number (a 10-bit number) is stored in the first part of a 16-bit number and then a 6-bit number is stored at the end.

How can I make use of bit-shifting to accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 8):

Note: I'm interpreting "first part of a 16 bit number" as the "10 least significant bits" - as bit-math usually counts backwards from the right.

```
short x = (short)(value & 1023); // the first 10 bits
short y = (short)((value >> 10) & 63); // the last 6 bits
```

and to recombine:

```
value = (short)(x | (y << 10));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<<` left shift operator, and the `|` binary or operator.

To put the values together:

```
short n = (short)(oneNumber << 6 | otherNumber);
```

(The values are cast to `int` by the binary operators, so you have to cast the result to `short`.)

To split the values:

```
int oneNumber = n >> 6;
int otherNumher = n && 0x3F;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ushort result=0;
ushort a=100;
ushort b= 43;
result=((result|(a<<6))|b&63)
```

`//shift a by 6 bits to empty 6 bits at end,and then OR it with result.Strip from b, any bit ahead of 6 th place and  OR it with result.`

Mathematically:-

```
0000000000000000 = result
0000000001100100 = a
0000000000101011 = b

0001100100000000 = (a<<6)
0000000000000000|0001100100000000 = (result|(a<<6))=0001100100000000
0000000000101011|0000000000111111 = b&63 =0000000000101011
0001100100000000|0000000000101011 = ((result|(a<<6))|b&63)=0001100100101011

result=6443
```